# Is it possible to dynamically create a link and click on it using Selenium?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, dynamic, hyperlink

Say there is a website that loads data dynamically using Ajax calls. The data runs to 200 pages with about 50 rows per page. Pagination is generated at the bottom which is like

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a class="paginate" id="previous">Previous</a>
    <span>
        <a class="paginate" id="p1">1</a>
        <a class="paginate" id="p2">2</a>
        <a class="paginate" id="p3">3</a>
        <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
        <a class="paginate" id="p200">200</a>
    </span>
    <a class="paginate" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Using Selenium with Java, is it possible to dynamically generate a link such as

```
<a class="paginate" id="p100">100</a>
```

and click on it, so as to directly go to page 100?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int lowerBound = 1;
        int upperBound = 11;
        
        int pageNum = rand.nextInt((upperBound - lowerBound)+1)+lowerBound;
        System.out.println("Page num generated "+pageNum);
        
        String xpathStr = ".//a[@id='p"+pageNum+"']";
        System.out.println(xpathStr);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathStr)).click();
```

Output:

```
Page num generated 8
.//a[@id='p8']
```